# Migrate MainCoroutineRule

Tags: junit, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I want create MainCoroutineRule.
But TestCoroutineScope deprecated since 1.6.0.
How can I migrate it?

Below is my MainCoroutineRule

```kotlin
class MainCoroutineRule(
    val dispatcher: TestCoroutineDispatcher =
        TestCoroutineDispatcher()
): TestWatcher(), TestCoroutineScope by TestCoroutineScope(dispatcher) {
    override fun starting(description: Description) {
        super.starting(description)
        Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)
    }
    
    override fun finished(description: Description) {
        super.finished(description)
        cleanupTestCoroutines()
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }
}
```

also, I want to use it on JUnit5.
What should I do to migrate TestWatcher?

Comment: I am trying to determine how to replace `cleanupTestCoroutines`. Did you come up with a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have so far, but I don't have a solution for `cleanupTestCoroutines`

```
class MainCoroutineRule(
    private val dispatcher: TestDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()
) : TestWatcher() {
    override fun starting(description: Description?) {
        super.starting(description)
        Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description?) {
        super.finished(description)
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }
}
```

Feel free to edit/modify this with a better solution

Comment: I added my answer.  
I use new version of coroutine and junit, so there are many difference with your code.
I hope it was helpful to you

Answer (score 1):

My solution will not be perfect, but it was my best.
According to [migration tips](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-test/MIGRATION.md), `runTest` does not support replacement for `cleanupTestCoroutines()`.
Instead of that, they support better structured concurrency.
So you don't need to worry about `cleanupTestCoroutines()`.

So, follow is my MainCoroutineExtension.

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class MainCoroutineExtension(
    private val testDispatcher: TestDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher(),
    val testScope: TestScope = TestScope(testDispatcher),
) : BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback {
    override fun beforeEach(context: ExtensionContext) {
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
    }

    override fun afterEach(context: ExtensionContext) {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }

}

@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
fun MainCoroutineExtension.runTest(
    block: suspend TestScope.() -> Unit
) = this.testScope.runTest {
    block()
}
```

> I use JUnit 5 and new coroutine.
> So I couldn't use `runBlockingTest` because it will be deprecated soon.
> If you have plan to migrate your coroutine, It will be helpful to you

Comment: I don't quite understand how that extension function would be used, but the migration guide makes it look very simple at the end: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-test/MIGRATION.md#simplify-code-by-removing-unneeded-entities